# Wordpress HTTP mixed content (jquery trying to load insecure image)

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, ssl, mixed-content

I have just installed SSL certificate to the website. However, When I open the webpage Google chrome does not show green padlock and when I look at the console it says that there is Mixed Content that causes the trouble. It is jQuery that tries to load this image which I have already made the changes in the script to load the secured one (https) Please see the attached image.

[image]

I have never seen anything like this before.Has anyone ever had this problem, please advice.

Thank you

Comment: The changes did not work, were incomplete or your looking at a cached version of the page; *loading.gif* clearly has a source of *http://* not *https://*

Comment: HI there, how do I view cached version of the page?

Comment: If you have changed the code and your changes aren't displaying, then _something_ is caching the old result. [WP docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/I_Make_Changes_and_Nothing_Happens) has some info on it that you might benefit from.

Comment: Thank you so much :) i'll look up to it